# How to solve No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource with angular 2 service written with angular-cli?

Tags: angular-cli, angular2-services

I have a url that pasting it inside the browser will give me a valid json response. Now, from my localhost, from inside angular-cli I'm trying to get that same json from a service and I get this:

```
No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:4200' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 403
```

I tried to read about this problem, but didn't understand what I need to do in order my service to work. I'm using angular-cli.

```
this.http.get(this.myUrl)
      .map(res => res.text())
      .subscribe(
        data => this.jsonResult = data,
        err => this.handleError(err),
        () => console.log('Random Quote Complete')
      );
```

This returns the error I get.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not with your app. You are trying to access a REST API from the browser and the server handling will need to be set so it accepts CORS requests.

It's not possible to give you more info without the back end and that would be a totally different question.